# How to change instafeeds limit on certain widths

Tags: jquery, instagram, feed

I can change the Instafeed limit by just changing the numbers in the script.
I was wondering if there was a way to write an if statement of a window width of < 600 or some number and set the limit to 4 then an else if for 800 then change the limit and so on. Sort of like break points you would write in CSS. Here is my script.

```
var feed = new Instafeed({
            get: 'tagged',

            limit: 12,
            resolution: "standard_resolution",
            after: function() {
                external();
        }
    });
        feed.run();
        function external(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#instafeed a').attr('target','_blank');
    });


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, check `window` width. Try

```
var InstafeedLimit = 12; // default

if($(window).width() < 800) {
    InstafeedLimit = 4; // change limit on screens less than 800px 
}

var feed = new Instafeed({
            get: 'tagged',
            limit: InstafeedLimit,
            resolution: "standard_resolution",
            after: function() {
                external();
        }
    });
        feed.run();
        function external(){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $('#instafeed a').attr('target','_blank');
    });

}
```